# Disable settings for files without extensions

Tags: vim, vimrc

I want to disable certain settings (like line numbers) when vim opens files that don't have an extension.

I have `set number` in my .vimrc, and I know that I could disable this for example for markdown files by using

```
autocmd filetype markdown setlocal nonumber
```

But, what would the filetype be for files without an extension? Or it can be done with a completely different approach?

Comment: "File without extension" or "file without filetype"? `Dockerfile` or `Makefile` don't have extensions but they certainly have a filetype (and syntax, etc.) and I am not sure you actually want to target those.

Comment: You are right. Do you think that targeting filetype would be a better approach? Is there even a way to distinguish text files that are do not belong in any other language/config?

Comment: Although I should add that currently I don't work with many makefiles or dockerfiles, so even if those had disabled numbers (going the extension route) it wouldn't affect me much. However a more complete solution would indeed not target makefiles and such.

Comment: My point was more that "file without extension" sounds both over-specified and under-specified, if that makes sense. I think that we all would benefit from some clarifications about the actual problem you are trying to solve. "File without extension" is relatively easy to do but it feels like it doesn't really fit your actual problem.

Comment: File extensions are something I control. If I want a file that is purely text (no programming languages or config or anything), I usually leave them without an extension. So I was wondering if a solution exists that wouldn't require me to change my workflow (ie. adding .txt or something)

Answer (score 2):

```
autocmd BufNewFile,BufRead * if expand('%:t') !~ '\.' | set nonumber | endif
```

`expand('%:t')` will get you the file name without full path. Then `!~ '\.'` will check that file name doesn't contain dot in it.

Comment: What if it's e.g. `.vimrc`? Not too sure that kind of dotfiles meets "no extension" criteria.

Comment: Then you can change the regex to `'.+\.'`

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to match on filetype, you can directly match on the file name in `BufRead` and `BufNewFile` autocommands. Note I have no idea whether you can easily match "no dots", but this should work:

```
set nonu
au BufNewFile,BufRead *.* setl nu
```

(This is also how you assign filetypes to unusual extensions that aren't autodetected right.)

Comment: So instead of having it on by default and disable it when not needed, have it off by default and enable it in all other cases?

Answer (score 1):

```
set number
augroup noextension
    autocmd!
    autocmd BufNewFile,BufRead * call NoExtension()
augroup END
function! NoExtension()
    if !expand('%:e') && !&filetype
        setlocal nonumber
    endif
endfunction
```

- The autocommand is triggered for any "file",
- `expand('%:e')` returns the extension so `!expand(%:e)` is true when there is no extension,
- similarly, `!&filetype` is true when there is no filetype set,
- if both are true, then we can be relatively confident that this is the kind of file we are interested in, and proceed.

Comment: Somehow this disabled the numbers for all files. I can't understand why, any help with debugging would be appreciated.